# Reading depth buffer in Android native code, using OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I'm creating an application where I render an image offscreen and I need to read the depth buffer.
The PC version of the application is easy, since I can use glGetTexImage or glReadPixels (using GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT). However now that I need to port the application to android, I have issues, since GL ES does not support glGetTexImage at all, and glReadPixel can be used only to read the color buffer (as I understood).

Many people suggest to render the depth buffer to a color buffer (or simply render the depth value into a color buffer), however as I understand, glReadPixel can read only 8 bit per channel values, and I need at least 16 bit per depth values.

My target android device is supporting OpenGL ES, so I was reading about Pixel Buffer Object, however it seams PBOs is only a faster method of transferring the data from the GPU, but to actually read the depth map I would still need to use glReadPixels to transfer the depth map into a PBO (which is not possible).

I was thinking that maybe creating an eglImage (wrappening my own buffer) and use that as the depth texture in the FBO might be a solution, but I don't have any experience with eglImages, so I'm not sure if this is even possible or not (and also this would work only on android, so I would need to have different implementations for PC and Android).

So, what is the best solution to access the depth map using OpenGL ES 3.0?

Comment: `glMapBufferRange()` on the PBO?

Comment: But how do I get the content into the PBO? AFAIK it's not possible to connect a PBO directly to an FBO as render target.

Comment: Sampling it as a depth texture, and rendering into a color buffer might indeed be your best option. For giving you the necessary accuracy, you could probably split the value into 2+ color components, and reassemble them after reading back. Or render into an integer format, there are a bunch with more than 8 bits of precision that are supported as render targets.